# Angular and Laravel 5. Filter not working with variable

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

This is a very strange behavior, but maybe I'm forgetting some small thing.
I have this filter on my blade.php:

```
ng-options="s.name for s in shareholders | filter: {email: '!' + newGrantOpts.userEmail} |orderBy:'name'">
```

The intention is to show all data except the data with newGrantOpts.userEmail.
I did a lot of tests to see if the variables involved have data and everything is ok. The strange thing is if i change the variable for one string like this:

```
ng-options="s.name for s in shareholders | filter: {email: '!example@example.com'} |orderBy:'name'">
```

Everything works flawless.
I printed newGrantOpts.userEmail to check the type and is string too, i'm really out of ideas.

Someone have some explanation for this ?
Thanks

Comment: It seems working correctly here in [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SqrckbfkCSwJcxTwQU96?p=preview)

Comment: I solved now, but using a different approach. I just removed the email in the backend and now the shareholders array is clean. I don't need the filter more.But if i find some solution i will post in the answer.